# How to produce error response in json

Tags: json, rest, exception, jax-rs

Am writing a Restful Webservice Impl, where i consume and produce response in JSON format by annotating `@Produces("application/json")`. Am producing JSON response as well. Here am handling exception with a class where it has error code and error message. When am getting exception it is not produced in `application/json` format. I used `ExceptionMapper` to find a solution but it is `text/plain format.

snippet

```
public Class Confiuration{
    @Path("getData")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public JSONGetDataResponseVo getData(GetDataRequestVo datarequestVO)
                                                          throws FaultResponse {
        JSONGetDataResponseVo response=new JSONGetDataResponseVo ();
        DataServiceValidator.validateGetConfigurationAndDataRequest(datarequestVO);
        ....
        ....
        }catch(ApplicationException applicationException){
            throw new FaultResponse(applicationException,locale);
        }  
}
```

FaultResponseMapper

```
@Provider
public class FaultResponseMapper implements ExceptionMapper<FaultResponse> {

    @Context
    private HttpHeaders headers;

    public Response toResponse(FaultResponse faultResponse) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .entity(faultResponse).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }

}
```

Application Exception

```
public abstract class ApplicationException extends Exception{

    private java.lang.String errorCode;

    public ApplicationException(String errorCode, String message) {
        super(message);
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }


    public ApplicationException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }



    public java.lang.String getErrorCode() {
        return this.errorCode;
    }


    public abstract String getLocaleMessage(Locale locale);

}
```

FaultResponse

```
public class FaultResponse extends WebApplicationException {

    private String errorCode;
    private String errorMessage;
    private String localErrorMessage;

    public FaultResponse(String errorCode, String errorMessage,
            String localErrorMessage) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
        this.localErrorMessage = localErrorMessage;
    }

    public FaultResponse(ApplicationException applicationException,
            Locale locale) {
        this.errorCode = applicationException.getErrorCode();
        this.errorMessage = applicationException.getMessage();
        if (locale != null
                && applicationException.getLocaleMessage(locale) != null) {
            this.localErrorMessage = applicationException
                    .getLocaleMessage(locale);
        } else {
            this.localErrorMessage = applicationException.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

So here how can i produce my faultResponse in JSON format.

Comment: This looks totally odd. Is `FaultResonse` an exception? I mean I guess it is because you are throwing it, but it just seems odd especially since you are also sending it as a response. If you were to map `ApplicationException`, it would seem more correct. You might want to show the `ApplicationException` class, as well as the `FaultResponse` class, for better help.

Comment: Did you check to see if the mapper is even being called? I would guess another mapper is being used, or the exception is bubbling to the container. Would need more complete information to test

Comment: Application exception is my abstract class where it will be extended by every exception class i use.updating application exception in the snippet

Comment: What about `FaultResponse`?

Comment: Also what implementation of JAX-RS or (server) are you using?

Comment: jersey 1.0.3 in WL 10.3.6

Comment: Without testing, what you've provided looks ok. I would guess for some reason the mapper is not being called (have you checked this?). Maybe the ApplicationException is bubbling up the container, and you are getting a container response (what is the actual response?). I would try and create mapper for ApplicationException and see what happens

Comment: 500 Internal server error    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl onException
SEVERE: Internal server error
com.exception.FaultResponse

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the fact that you are returning an exception as a response. I would

1. Make an exception mapper for `ApplicationException`.
2. Refactor `FaultResponse` to not extend and exception. Just create it in the mapper.
3. In order to see the response, you will need to send a status other than No Content. You can't have a body in it. Send somethng like Bad Request.
4. You can just declare the resource method as `throws ApplicationException`. You don't need to catch it and rethrow.

I've made these changes, and it works fine.

---

#### UPDATE: with complete test

Added getters (required for marshalling) to `FaultResponse` and remove the exception extension

```
public class FaultResponse {
    ...
    public String getErrorCode() { return errorCode; }
    public String getErrorMessage() { return errorMessage; }
    public String getLocalErrorMessage() { return localErrorMessage; }
    ...
}
```

Created a Service for testing and `ApplicationException` implementation

```
public class ApplicationExceptionImpl extends ApplicationException { 
    public ApplicationExceptionImpl(){
        this("400", "Bad Request");
    }

    public ApplicationExceptionImpl(String errorCode, String message) {
        super(errorCode, message);
    }

    @Override
    public String getLocaleMessage(Locale locale) {
        return "Bad Request";
    }  
}

public class FaultService {
    public void doSomething() throws ApplicationException {
        throw new ApplicationExceptionImpl();
    }
}
```

Resource class

```
@Path("fault")
public class FaultResource {
    
    FaultService service = new FaultService();
    
    @GET
    public Response getException() throws ApplicationException {
        service.doSomething();
        return Response.ok("Cool").build();
    }
}
```

ExceptionMapper

```
@Provider
public class ApplicationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ApplicationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ApplicationException exception) {
        FaultResponse response = new FaultResponse(exception, Locale.ENGLISH);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity(response).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }  
}
```

ApplicationException class is left the same

> `curl -v http://localhost:8080/api/fault`
> `{"errorCode":"400","errorMessage":"Bad Request","localErrorMessage":"Bad Request"}`

If after this you are still not seeing JSON, it's possible you do not have a provider configured. If this is the case, please show your application configuration, along with your project dependencies.

Comment: Seems like Mapper is not called to produce JSON media type as response

Comment: I forgot what I did exactly, I deleted the project. I think I made a implementation `ApplicationExceptionImpl`. I think I was able to still use `ApplicationException` for the mapper though. Also I have to create  a simple service for testing, and threw the `ApplicationExceptionImpl` from a service method, which I called in the resource class.

Comment: After your comments, made my Application Exception class which is an abstract class into my exception mapper and i didn't extened any thing in fault response class. Made my resource to throw application Exception. But still it is not producing in json type

Comment: on debugging my code exception throwing at ApplicationExceptionImpl class. It is not going through mapper class(provider class).

Comment: Root cause of ServletException.
com.sun.jersey.api.container.MappableContainerException:

Comment: It's hard to say what causes that. Can you try and run the complete example I've posted and see what happens. Also one thing to keep in mind is that only one exception mapper can be called per request cycle. This is to avoid infinite loops. If for some reason another exception is being thrown, that exception will bubble up to the container level and the container will handle the response. I don't know what else to say, as I can not reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you cannot find the problem, maybe create a new small project that reproduces the problem, and GitHub it, and I can try test it to see what the problem might be.

Comment: When Exception is thrown it is not getting into Mapper. may be this is the reason am not getting as JSON format (Where we convert media type to json)

Comment: I would check the mapper is configured. How do you register your providers/resources? Is it with package scanning? Do you explicitly register it? As you can see, my code, in a application on it's own works. So it is not a problem with the mapper. It could be your configuration or it could be another exception is thrown prior to, I don't know. If I don't have something to test, I can only guess.

Comment: Yes it worked for me when i upgrade my jersey bundle to 1.0.0.0_1-1-5-1, which comes as shared library in weblogic server. It automatically detect my provider class on bootup. Thanks @peeskillet

Comment: What do you mean? If you mean different kinds of `ApplicationExceptions`, then you can either create a different mapper for each subtype or you can just check `instanceof`. If you mean what if other exceptions occur, well you don't really have too much control. What I mean by a different exception occurring is some time after the first mapper has been called. For instance another exception can occur during the mapper call; an exception can occur in a filter; an exception can occur while marshalling your JSON exception respnse. You really don't have too much control over this...

Comment: ...You basically need to try your best to check for exceptional cases in any other components under your control, that would occur after the mapper call. In most cases it is just filters. There should be an marshalling exception in the mapper, as you have control over the response object.

Comment: This is set in place so there are no infinite loops. For instance We have a mapper for JacksonMappingException, and we send a response object as JSON and we get another JSONMappingException. It would go in an infinite loop. So it's in place to protect us. We should do out best to work around that